# placing text on top of a sketch in p5.js

Tags: javascript, css, p5.js

I am trying to create my first website using the p5.js library, with the end goal being an online digital portfolio. I am currently working on a splash screen, in which I have some large title text filling the center of the screen on a simple black background, which actively resizes to fill the window.

I would like to place a simple doodle in the background to add some interest. My challenge is that I would not like this doodle to draw on top of my text, but instead place it underneath my text. Initially I was thinking of infinitely redrawing the text so it stays at the top, however I have deduced there is no way to do this while still animating something beneath it.

My knowledge of HTML / CSS is minimal, however I was thinking of making the background of the title sketch transparent, a separate sketch with the doodle, and use the z index property in CSS to place the doodle beneath the title, is this even possible?

Thanks!

Further edits based on recommendations:

```
function preload() {
  myFont = loadFont('assets/HighTide.otf');
}

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  title = text("Welcome", width/2, height/2);
  background(30);
  fsize = window.innerHeight/4;
  pg = createGraphics(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(30);

  pg.fill(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255));
  //pg.translate(width/2, height/2);
  pg.ellipse(random(window.innerWidth), random(window.innerHeight), 60, 60)

  image(pg, 0, 0);

  textFont(myFont);
  textSize(fsize);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  fill(255);
  text("Welcome", width/2, height/2);
  }

window.onresize = function() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.size(w,h);
  fsize = window.innerHeight/4;
  title.textSize(fsize);
  width = w;
  height = h;
}
```

Comment: HTML/CSS has a `position` property that I think is what you want. In conjunction with `z-index` you mention, you can position elements on top of one another and get the effect you are looking for. https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on exactly how you're drawing everything, but if you're doing this all in P5.js then you've already described exactly what you need to do.

**Step 1:** Each frame, clear out old frames by calling the `background()` function.

**Step 2:** Then draw your doodle.

**Step 3:** Finally, draw your text. Since you're drawing the text after the doodle, it shows up "on top" of the doodle.

This is how most P5.js sketches work: every frame, you clear out the old frames and then draw the next frame.

**Edit:** If you need a sketch that doesn't clear out old frames but still shows two different layers (your doodle and your text), then what you could do is draw your doodle to a buffer, then draw that buffer each frame, then draw the text on top of the buffer. Check out the `createGraphics()` function in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics).

Comment: In theory this should work, however my "doodle" is progressive, it builds upon itself, so having it clear out everything each time doesn't necessarily achieve what I am looking for. I will edit my question to include my attempt of the above ^

Comment: further edits above, everything works, how would I go about resizing my pg Graphics element responsively the same way my background and text does?

Comment: @Arkadelic Stack Overflow isn't really designed for this type of back and forth, so if you have follow-up questions you should post them in their own new question posts. That being said, basically you'd just create a new buffer with the correct size and draw the old buffer to it using the `image()` function which takes parameters for scaling.

Comment: Understood, thank you and excuse my lack of proper etiquette!

Comment: @Arkadelic No problem, just figured I'd save you the trouble of editing you post over and over. Just make a new one. Good luck!